# How to call newly made variable

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to calculate the difference between the total count of elements in the "nara_current_wvl" layer and the "same_points" variable created here, and than the difference between the total count of elements in the "nara_2050_wvl" layer and the "same_points" variable. I don't know how I can call the newly variable and the layers without the constraints put on them. For context the "same_points" variable here represent trees that are present in both layers and the buffer is used to check this. Then the first difference are trees that are deforested and the second difference are the afforested trees.

```
select count(fut."gid") as same_points
from nara_current_wvl cur
inner join nara_2050_wvl fut
on st_within(fut."geom", st_buffer(cur."geom", 20));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There are many possible, more or less elegant and performant solutions in SQL - this one attempts to stay within basic `JOIN` set theory.*

***Theoretically*** you would create a `FULL OUTER JOIN` result set and `COUNT` *set intersection* vs. *set non-intersection*:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(fut."gid") AS cur__difference_to_same_points,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(cur."gid") AS fut__difference_to_same_points,
FROM
  nara_current_wvl AS cur
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  nara_2050_wvl AS fut
    ON ST_DWithin(cur.geom, fut.geom, 20)
;
```

***However:***
The functional expression used as condition (`ON ST_DWithin`) here **is neither *hash*able nor *merge*able** as a virtual join set, and thus **cannot be used in a `FULL OUTER JOIN`**.

---

***Practically*** a common workaround would be to `UNION` `LEFT` & `RIGHT` specific `OUTER JOIN`s inside a sub-query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(fut_gid) AS cur__difference_to_same_points,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(cur_gid) AS fut__difference_to_same_points
FROM (
  SELECT
    cur."gid" AS cur_gid, fut."gid" AS fut_gid
  FROM
    nara_current_wvl AS cur
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    nara_2050_wvl AS fut
      ON ST_DWithin(cur.geom, fut.geom, 20)
  UNION
  SELECT
    cur."gid" AS cur_gid, fut."gid" AS fut_gid
  FROM
    nara_current_wvl AS cur
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    nara_2050_wvl AS fut
      ON ST_DWithin(cur.geom, fut.geom, 20)
) AS q
;
```

---

**Notes:**

- ***Never*** use an `ST_Buffer` for proximity checks - `ST_DWithin` is fundamentally faster *and* makes efficient use of the spatial index
- Make sure you understand the units of your *Coordinate Reference System* and how that affects measurements; the `20` both in your call to `ST_Buffer` and my `ST_DWithin` **assume the units of the underlying *CRS*** of your geometries; meaning that, if their coordinates represented *degree* values, `20` would be treated as `20 degrees` - and *degrees* are useless as distance measure and proximity thresholds
- "*But the repeated calls to* `COUNT(*)`*?*"; `COUNT(*)` *is* indeed considerably costly, and if you feel this to be a bottleneck - e.g. because the tables are very very large - create all `COUNT`s needed in this query *once*, wrap all up into another sub-query and reuse those counts there

Comment: Thanks, I have learned much from this reponse. The CRS is in meters, this I have checked and indeed I got the error that the table is not hashable or mergeable. The solution with union got the answer I wanted in 343 msec so the tables aren't too large for the count(*) to be a real problem.